# Unit test angular 1 directive with $on

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

Within this directive, I want to test the following:

```
$scope.$on('loggedMsg', function(){
   if($scope.users.length){
       $scope.callingFn();
   }
});
```

I am able to emit `loggedMsg` and with `$scope.apply()`, it will call the $scope.callingFn(). Is there a way to not actually call $scope.callingFn, but just spy on it? I am using mocha and sinon to write these unit tests. Is what I am suggesting possible?

```
describe('testing directive', function(){
   const elemScope = element.isolateScope;
   it('should trigger callingFn if loggedMsg is emitted', function(){
       scope.$emit('loggedMsg');
       scope.$apply();
       //elemScope.callingFn will be called due to the apply. Is there a way to just spy on that fn being called?
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Sinon` to stub a function, calling that (now stubbed) function will not call the original.

`Stubs` also support the full `Spy` API, meaning we can use a `Stub` to make sure the original method doesn't get called and also see under what conditions it was called (such as how many times, with what parameters).

Using your example test:

```
describe('testing directive', function(){
   const scope = element.isolateScope;
   it('should trigger callingFn if loggedMsg is emitted', function(){
       const stub = sinon.stub(scope, 'callingFn');
       scope.$emit('loggedMsg');
       scope.$apply();
       assert(stub.called);
   });
});
```

---

Documentation reference: http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.1.2/stubs/